# Attributes not appearing in grids like "add crosssell products" - data migration caused issue

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute, cross-sells

I have a magento site that was created by the official data migration, but recently I added 2 attributes post migration.

Today I noticed that the "`add related/crossell/upsell`" grid displays these two attributes. But none of mine. No combination of configuration options changes that.

So I am puzzled as to why, and how.

Alas these new attributes aren't attributes of particular value there but I would love to have other attributes show in these tables it would help a lot.

The same attributes also end up showing by default in the admin product grid for a brand new user, which I am assuming is related.

I could not see anything in the settings and I have been looking around the code :-

```
app\code\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\CrosssellGrid.php
app\code\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Crosssell.php
app\code\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Crosssell.php
app\code\Magento\Catalog\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_product_crosssellgrid.xml
app\code\Magento\Catalog\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_product_crosssell.xml
```

I can't find anything relevant

I am assuming it is another case where Magento Admin has put logic in its admin interface that should be at the code or database defaults level.

Anyone encountered that?

Comment: I know they tell us not to mess in the database but had I looked there first I would have saved LOADS of time

I compared the data in the database tables and found is_visible_in_grid = 1 for these new attributes and attributes created by extensions , BUT 0 for all migrated attributes. Indeed, setting this to 1 fixes the issue.
But there is no way to set this to 1 in the admin interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution alas in this case is to fix the attributes direct in the database!

In the database table `catalog_eav_attribute` there is a column `is_visible_in_grid`

If it is set to 1 the attribute will appear by default in product grids, the main one or the related/upsell/crossell ones

It was set to 1 for user created new attributes and many attributes created by extensions, but it was set to 0 for all migrated attributes.

Setting this to 1 fixed the issue.

NOTE: there is no normal way to set this to 1 in the admin interface as the field is hidden

**Why it happens:**

First `is_visible_in_grid` is set to be invisible in the attribute management screens (if it was visible all this would not be a bug)

On creation of an attribute, that invisible field defaults to 1, this is configured in the interface block `app\code\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Advanced.php`. All user created attributes are therefore created with `is_visible_in_grid` ON

On the other hand `is_visible_in_grid` is set to default to 0 in the database definition. programmatically created attributes need to set it to 1 or else attributes are created with `is_visible_in_grid` OFF

data migration ignores that attribute, so all user created attributes end up migrated with `is_visible_in_grid` OFF when it should be ON.

I have filed a bug with the data migration github https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/809